# typescript array.map lost returned type

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary, types

I would expect a type error in the following code, but for typescript is perfectly ok, can you tell me why?

```
export interface Structure {
    aaa: string;
}

export function f1(): Structure[] {  // OK for typescript, not for me
    const result = [].map(certState => {
        return {
            aaa: 'aaa',
            ADDITIONAL_FIELD: 'asdf'
        }
    });

    return result;
}

export function f2(): Structure[] { // ERROR for typescript (and for me)
        return [
            {
                aaa: 'sdf',
                ADDITIONAL_FIELD: 'asdf'
            }
        ]
    }
```

[Here is the link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Structure%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20aaa%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20f1()%3A%20Structure%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20%5B%5D.map(certState%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20aaa%3A%20'sdf'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ADDITIONAL_FIELD%3A%20'asdf'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the fact that in `f2()` you are directly returning your result.

If you changed `f2()` to be

```
export function f2(): Structure[] {
    const returnVal = [
        {
            aaa: 'sdf',
            ADDITIONAL_FIELD: 'asdf'
        }
    ]

    return returnVal;
}
```

then there would be no compiler error.

TypeScript uses [structural typing](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#structural) to determine type compatibility, so in your code for `f1()`, `result` is of type

```
{
   aaa: string,
   ADDITIONAL_FIELD: string
}[]
```

which is compatible with `Structure[]` (there is no danger in type narrowing).

I'm not 100% sure why directly returning doesn't work, but my assumption is that in `f2()` you are telling the compiler that "this specific array is of type `Structure[]`" 
and it says no it's not. When you have an intermediate variable in `f1()` you are saying "this function returns `Structure[]`" and when you return the intermediate variable the compiler checks and says "okay `result` matches `Structure[]`" so this function is doing what it says.

I'd be curious to hear if others have a more rigorous explanation

Answer (score 0):

I just learn that Typescript has a concept of exact types only for object literals, so f1 is not using object literals, so additional properties cannot be add and it's valid for typescript. f2 uses object literals, so additional properties are not allowed. This scare me a lot, but that's how typescript works